# Execute program with -- parameters in bash script

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to run the following command in a bash script:

```
antimicro --profile none.xml
```

In terminal it runs perfectly but not through bash, I've tried " and ' and [], just doesn't work..

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please let us know which error message you're getting (if any).

Answer (score 1):

The path to `none.xml` will be relative to `$PWD` when running the script, **not** relative to the script. You can either refer to the file with an absolute path, a relative path from `$PWD`, or a relative path from the script using [`"$(cd "$(dirname "${BASH_SOURCE\[0\]}")" && pwd)"`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/246128/96588).

Comment: Solved! Thank you very much that helped allot.

Comment: Since this solved your problem, could you please mark it as such?